# angular directive always adds attributes to wrapping outer element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I'm new to angular and banging my head against the wall over this:

I am making a re-usable slider element which will generate an input type="range" wrapped in a label.

I want the attributes defined on the directive to be applied to the child input element defined in the directive's template, which they do, but they also get added to the wrapping label element. This seems messy and I think I'm missing something fundamental.

What is the best way to do this? do I need to use a compile function, that seems like it would defeat the purpose of having a template in the directive?

current html:

```
<slider min="0" max="1000" step="1" label="foo" ng-model="slider1" value="750">
</slider>
```

current directive:

```
myApp.directive('slider', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{
        data:'=ngModel',
        min:'@',
        max:'@',
        step:'@',
        label:'@',
        value:'='
    },
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<label>{{label}}<input min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" step="{{step}}" type="range" ng-model="data" value="{{value}}" />{{data}}</label>'
};
```

});

current output:

```
<label min="0" max="1000" step="1" label="foo" ng-model="slider1" value="250" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding">
    foo
    <input min="0" max="1000" step="1" type="range" ng-model="data" value="250" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</label>
```

desired output:

```
<label>
    foo
    <input min="0" max="1000" step="1" type="range" ng-model="data" value="250" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Though i haven't tried, i would guess the replace is adding the attributes of the **slider** element to the first element in your template which is label. Try adding another element in the template before your label, and try if replace: false does the same

```
<div class="filler></div><label>{{label}}<input min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" step="{{step}}" type="range" ng-model="data" value="{{value}}" />{{data}}</label>
```

**UPDATE**

Since replate:true always seems to add the attributes, you will probably have to use replace:false, and create a compile or link function that deletes the element manually as in

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {    angular.element(element).remove();
```

Comment: yes it always adds the attributes to the first element, is this default behaviour? Can it be disabled?

Comment: removing the replace option, does stop the attributes being added to the wrapping label, but then the slider element is present with all the attributes in the resulting html.  I just noticed if I put a div in front like in your answer I get the error: Template for directive 'slider' must have exactly one root element.

Comment: well then you will probably have to use **replace:false**, and create a compile or link function that deletes the element manually as in

`link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   angular.element(element).remove();`

Comment: yes, however I'm not using more than one root element, it is just always automatically adding to the root element. It does sound like I might need to use a compile function, which is what I suspected. But I wanted to be sure this was the way it was meant to be done. I understand the need to maybe bring over a class etc. Just seems strange theres no way to turn off this default behaviour of adding of the attributes given they are defined and mapped in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is a few months old so you've probably moved on now but I kinda just want to answer it anyway. Maybe it'll help other people.

I've only been using AngularJS for around 3 weeks now but I get the feeling that the messy output you're getting is typical of AngularJS and after all it's only messy if you're delving around in the generated html. AngularJS seems not to care too much about polluting the html with tags and attributes - it seems (to me in my opinion at least) to be about making reusable components and bits and making it easier to use them while coding.

I have found it's best not to use replace because then when you're inspecting your html it is harder to tell whether you've just used your directive or whether you simply put the html directly in the page. Additionally the docs mention that it's only real use case is for when you're generating SVG documents.

Let me use your example here to illustrate what I'm trying to say:

Source:

```
<some html />
<slider min="0" max="1000" step="1" label="foo" ng-model="slider1" value="750" />
<some other html />
```

Your desired result:

```
<some html />
<label>
    text
    <input min="0" max="1000" step="1" type="range" ng-model="data" value="250" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" />
</label>
<some other html />
```

Result with replace:

```
<some html />
<label min="0" max="1000" step="1" label="foo" ng-model="slider1" value="250" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding">
    text
    <input min="0" max="1000" step="1" type="range" ng-model="data" value="250" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" />
</label>
<some other html />
```

Result without replace:

```
<some html />
<slider min="0" max="1000" step="1" label="foo" ng-model="slider1" value="250" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding">
    <label>
        text
        <input min="0" max="1000" step="1" type="range" ng-model="data" value="250" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" />
    </label>
</slider>
<some other html />
```

I would suggest that when you're inspecting the html and you see your desired result how will you know whether you just wrote in the html or whether you used a directive. In the result without replace however the directive is explicitly named and it'll be impossible to mistake it for anything else. Also the html that gets inserted looks exactly like you expected it to without additional attributes on the label.

Of course you could use the compile function to remove the excess elements or attributes as mentioned by @frank but again I would suggest that this would still make your generated html less clear than the result without replace.

I would also just point out for future viewers of this question that the replace option of AngularJS directives is deprecated bearing this notice in the documentation: ([DEPRECATED!], will be removed in next major release - i.e. v2.0)

See documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-